# black&white to color image in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am doing simple image processing in matlab. I turned my original image (jpg) into black and white image with the function im2bw and I did some modifications on this image. Do you know if it is possible to turn again this image to the original colors?

Comment: You unfortunately can't, but you can apply a colour map to the grayscale image to pseudo-colour it.  Check out `ind2rgb` and `colormap` for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grayscaling an image is a one-way function. Without the original data, you have no way of determining the hue of the color used before it was converted to grayscale, and so there is actually loss of data in the conversion.